# Display posts from specific categories on page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display specific category on page by id.
I'm using this code(still displaying all the categories):

```
<?php 
    $categories = get_categories(); 
    foreach ($categories as $category) :
?>
<section>
    <div>
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
                                'cat' => array(2,6,9,13)
                );  
       ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what is the out put share your complete code. Which is the file name where you written this code

Comment: This Line — `'cat' => array(2,6,9,13)` says *Fetch all Posts which match any category with id: 2, 6, 9, 13*. And by the way; it is doubtful that You'd get anything back since the `$args` is not executed at all except if you have some code you are not showing...

Comment: You need show your entire code to get a better answer or help from some one the code you've provided is not enough for the community to understand your problem ans help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` clause; that way you can query the each element and do something when the value is `true` or `false`.

Then if the `$category` does not meet the requirement, use `continue` to skip it over.

Or you can do it the other way, and skip if the `$category` equals a certain value.

For example:

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    if($category != 'SOME_CATEGORY')
    {
        continue;
    }
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
      'cat' => array(2,6,9,13)
    ); 
}
```

Another method is to create the array inside of your `if` clause:

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    if($category == 'SOME_CATEGORY')
    {
        $args = array(
          'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
          'cat' => array(2,6,9,13)
        ); 
    }
}
```

If your array `$categories` is a `key`=>`value` then keep in mind you have to add specify the key under the `$category` variable. Or else, you will get an error of PHP trying to convert an Array to String.

For example: `$category['key']`. If it's a simple 1d array don't worry about that.